# Bolt CMS fake requests for different domains

Tags: php, symfony, bolt-cms

I'm trying to fake requests in a Bolt CMS. The reason is, that I want to generate a static HTML Version of the Site. Using the `Sitemap`extension I got a list of available URLs.

I'm using the Symfony Request class to fake an URI by running `$app->run($request)` where `$request` is an instance of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request`

The problem with that is, that It will throw some errors complaining about missing template files.

My question is what settings need to be tweaked to persuade bolt to answer correctly to my fake requests?

Comment: add the errors you get

Comment: The error I get is the following: ```<h1>
    Bolt - Fatal error.
</h1>

<ul>
    <li>Class: Twig_Error_Loader</li>
    <li>Message: Template &quot;entry.twig&quot; is not defined ().</li>
    <li>Code: 0</li>
</ul>``` I guess its due to the path and host modifications I try to accomplish